# Screen hibernation in dual-screen extended mode

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hibernate

On my desktop computer, I run a Windows 10 config on dual-screen in extended mode.

However, whenever I put my computer into hibernation, my main screen (Philips 236v4, VGA) will turn off but my secondary screen (Samsung s22d300, HDMI) will only turn to power-save mode, displaying a glowing black screen with an ugly moving "check signal cable HDMI" message.

I tried several situations when hibernating, with Philips as main and Samsung as secondary:

- extended mode `-->` power saving (my very problem)
- main screen only `-->` turned off (expected behavior)
- duplicate screen `-->` power saving

The problem remains if I swap my Samsung s22d300 as the main screen, it doesn't turn off while the Philips does.

Both screens are plugged on an old NVidia GeForce GTX 650 (2 GB) with fully updated drivers. The device manager only displays two "generic plug and play monitor" drivers though.

Is there a way I can actually turn off my Samsung s22d300 when I make my computer hibernate?

**EDIT:** I just tried, the exact same happens when I turn my computer off

Comment: The scenario you describe has nothing to do with your computer, but how your monitors' firmwares behaves while it is powered on, but not receiving a video signal.  Looking at the Samsung manual for your monitor, it appears the closest option you have is to automatically turn off the monitor after 1 hour at minimum. To do this, on the monitor OSD: Menu > Setup&Reset > Off Timer (on) > Turn Off After (1 hr).  The only other option is to press the power button on the monitor manually when you turn your pc off or hibernate.  Hope this helps you understand your situation!

Comment: @Blaelph the funny thing is that the Samsung monitor behaves correctly when I select the "main screen only" display mode, even if it is powered on but not receiving a video signal. If there was no way to have the expected behavior, I would share your opinion and give up, but here, this behavior is different depending on the display mode. Don't you think this is a hint that there might be a solution?

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly that when you say it behaves correctly as "main screen only", the Philips is set in Windows to be the main screen and the Samsung is disabled in Windows?  When the Samsung behaves correctly, does it still have the power LED illuminated, but perhaps turn to an amber color or does it completely shut off?  Considering your extensive testing with various configurations, my only further suggestion at this point is to see if you can download a Samsung monitor driver to replace the generic "Plug and Play" one and see if that gives you the option to set it as you wish.